# How can wizards avoid Trelawney's statement when dining with 13 people?

Tags: harry-potter, prophecy, sybill-trelawney

Trelawney's statement:

> Never forget that when thirteen dine together, the first to rise will be the first to die!

This statement was proven to be correct multiple times throughout the series. But, what are wizards supposed to do when dining with 13 people to avoid marking 1 person to die first?

Waiting until a 14th person joins the table would be a correct answer, but lets say that's not an option here, what should they do?

Comment: This isn't just a wizard tradition. The trope dates back (allegedly) to Jesus and his disciples. In Victorian times if there were 13 at the table they'd invite a server to join them.

Comment: Traditionally you lay a 14th place and put a teddy bear in the seat. Dining with 13 has long been considered unlucky.

Comment: "This statement was proven to be correct multiple times throughout the series." Was it? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: In the series, there's only one occurrence of 13 people dining together. So, it was hardly "proven to be correct multiple times throughout the series". Plus, we all know that Trelawney was a fraud most of the time.

Comment: There were multiple occasions, at least 2 where we are certain, being Christmas dinner when Dumbledore rose first and the dinner at the order's HQ where Sirius rose first, there were also 13 people together after the battle of the 7 Harry's, but we don't know if they had dinner and we also don't even know who died first later on in the book,... But at least 2 is multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of any 13 people, someone has to die first, yeah? Doesn’t mean it has to be *soon*. And let’s say the same family of 13 dined together every day, and someone different leaves the table first each time; it makes the prophecy into a kind of random draw — which is the default situation without a prophecy. So I’m thinking mostly they don’t care.

Comment: While it may not be soon, it's still not nice to know you'd die first of the group. I like the idea of avoiding it by dining with the same people multiple times, thanks.